Intermittent "Connection Timeout Expired" from an ASP.NET Core Web API to SQL Server database
Recently (in the last month) I have been getting hangs in the API and checking the logs I am seeing this:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement


I have set the connection pool to 3k and timeout to 60s.
The API is an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API deployed on an Azure App Service
The API uses EF Core to connect to the database
The database is an Azure SQL database using the Standard tier (DTU based purchasing model)
Nothing seems wrong database side when you check the metrics everything is consistently very low.
There are not long running queries (3 second is the longest for a very specific call)
Database is configured to allow networked Azure apps to access it (firewall) and this works fine most of the time

Semi regularly the front end hangs and a single call can take a few minutes to return (that would usually take < 1 second). Upon checking the logs I see the error above.
Note: The database is responsive when this error is thrown from the deployed API and there are not that many connections seen using sp_who2. I have 2 APIs pointing to this same database and both experience this hang/timeout when whatever event it is occurs.
From what I gather the request is never leaving the client (API), could this be an Azure networking issue? If not this, anyone have an idea on why this is happening?

So it turned out I needed to up my Azure Resource plan since it was maxxing out the CPU at 100% pretty regularly. After this was upgraded I stopped getting the issues described above.
